# Rails: loading association at once vs multiple tiny queries

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I've got a situation. I am rendering a paginated collection of resources(let's say Posts). I need to show whether the post is liked by the current user. So basically we have three tables: posts, users and likes(a join table o indicate if users like some posts).

I came up with three solutions:

```
class Post
# 1
  def liked_by?(user)
    likes.exists?(user: user) # usage: Post.limit(50).map { |post| [p.id, post.liked_by?(current_user)] }
  end

# 2
  def liked_by?(user)
    likes.any? { |like| like.user_id == user.id } # usage: Post.limit(50).includes(:likes).map { |post| [p.id, post.liked_by?(current_user)] }
  end


# 3
  def liked_by?(user)
    user.likes.exists?(post: self) # usage: Post.limit(50).includes(:likes).map { |post| [p.id, post.liked_by?(current_user)] }
  end

# 4
  def liked_by?(user)
    user.likes.any? { |like| like.user_id == user.id } # usage: Post.limit(50).map { |post| [p.id, post.liked_by?(current_user)] }
  end
end
```

I can imagine the advantages and disadvantages of each of them but would be happy to hear any thoughts from you guys.

Usually, we render 50 posts at a time and the current user has about a hundred likes, but some users have thousands of likes so it's hard to say that there is a general solution for this. Anyway, I'm open to hear your proposals. Probably there's way # 5...(like denormalizing tables, materialized views and etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the above as they will all create a N+1 query issue. Also interrogation methods (methods that end with `?`) should by convention return a boolean in Ruby.

You can use `EXISTS` with a subquery:

```
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT "likes".* FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."user_id" = $1 AND "likes"."post_id" = "posts"."id")
```

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes
end
```

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :likes

  # returns posts liked by user
  def self.liked_by_user(user)
    where(
      user.likes
          .where(Like.arel_table[:post_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
          .arel.exists
    )
  end
end
```

If you want all the posts regardless if the have been liked or not and a boolean indicating if they have been liked by the user can put that same EXISTS into the SELECT clause:

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  # ...

  # selects posts and a liked_by_user boolean
  def self.with_likes_by_user(user)
    columns = self.respond_to?(:arel) ? arel.projections : arel_table[Arel.star]
    select(
      columns, 
      user.likes
          .where(Like.arel_table[:post_id].eq(arel_table[:id]))
          .arel.exists.as('liked_by_user')
    )
  end
end
```

```
SELECT 
  "posts".*, 
  EXISTS (
    SELECT "likes".* 
    FROM "likes" WHERE "likes"."user_id" = $1 
    AND "likes"."post_id" = "posts"."id"
  ) AS liked_by_user 
FROM "posts"
```

Comment: Good answer but `joins(:likes).where(likes: { user_id: user.id })` shouldn't work - it will filter out the posts without the user likes.

Comment: You have to change it with custom (Arel) outer join with 2 conditions.

Comment: And even after that, it's a good question which way (EXISTS subquery/LEFT OUTER JOIN) has best performance. I'm sure there is no definite answer.

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk I removed the join alternative as I mostly included it for completeness.

Comment: Such a perfect answer. Thank you a lot. That's what I need to. I was going to use my #4 option. That would add one db hit to retrieve all likes for the specific user then I would do a search for post id presence of each post in that array. But your query even better.